# Dynamic Query SELECT INTO #TmpTbl not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I'm having issues with the following:

```
DECLARE @TmpMemberTypeCount NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @TmpMemberTypeCount =
    N'SELECT DISTINCT
        StoreID
        ,AgreedDate
        ,'+'''TotalCount'''+' as Type
        ,'+ @MemberTypeCols + '
      INTO #TmpMemberTypeCount
      FROM #TmpTbl as t

      PIVOT
      (
        SUM(CP_Count)
        FOR MemberShipType
        IN (' + @MemberTypePvt + ')
    ) as p
    GROUP BY StoreID
        ,AgreedDate'

EXEC (@TmpMemberTypeCount)
```

When I run this I don't get an error, however if I try to run

```
SELECT * FROM #TmpMemberTypeCount
```

I get the error that basically says the table has not been created yet.

If I change the `INTO #TmpMemberTypeCount` to `INTO TmpMemberTypeCount` everything works fine.

Is it not possible to use a temp table with a dynamic query?

Another note is that if I change the `EXEC` to `PRINT` and then run what is printed, everything runs fine and the temp table is created.

UPDATE:

The reason I need to use a `#TmpTbl` is because I'm pivoting out the distinct membertypes for each store. So if 2 users are running this report at the same time, the columns in `#TmpTbl` for user1 could be:

```
StoreID,
AgreedDate,
Type,
User, -- MemberType1
Admin, -- MemberType2
Staff, -- MemberType3
```

The columns in `#TmpTbl` for user2 could be:

```
StoreID,
AgreedDate,
Type,
Trainer, -- MemberType1
Chef, -- MemberType2
CoatCheck, -- MemberType3
Painter -- MemberType4
```

The MemberTypes are stored in `@MemberTypeCols` like `Trainer, Chef, CoatCheck, Painter`

Comment: One thing you forget is that **local temp table is per context** using EXEC you switch to different context and when finish EXEC the temp table is gone, when you use normal table it persists no matter of context.

Answer (score 0):

of course,
when you execute this command

```
EXEC (@TmpMemberTypeCount)
```

the query was lunched in a new session, with a new id.

the temp table exist only in the session where was created.

when you exec the command

```
SELECT * FROM #TmpMemberTypeCount
```

you are executing the query in a different session.
you must use a real table, or a global temp teble ##

Comment: With a global temp table, if 2 users are running this report at the same time they would both be using the same table? unlike a regular temp table where both users would have their own table?

Comment: Global temporary tables are visible to all SQL Server connections. When you create one of these, all the users can see it.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TmpMemberTypeCount NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @TmpMemberTypeCount =
    N'SELECT DISTINCT
        StoreID
        ,AgreedDate
        ,'+'''TotalCount'''+' as Type
        ,'+ @MemberTypeCols + '
      INTO #TmpMemberTypeCount
      FROM #TmpTbl as t

      PIVOT
      (
        SUM(CP_Count)
        FOR MemberShipType
        IN (' + @MemberTypePvt + ')
    ) as p
    GROUP BY StoreID
        ,AgreedDate

   SELECT * FROM #TmpMemberTypeCount'   --<-- add this here 

EXEC (@TmpMemberTypeCount)
```

Dynamic sql has its own scope anything created in dynamic sql will not be visible to any outer scope

Comment: Is it possible to basically do an `EXEC (@TmpMemberTypeCount INTO #TmpTbl)` I know that won't work but something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

The temp table created on the fly in the dynamic SQL is created in a different session and that is why it can't be accessed in your case (as Mattia Caputo mentioned).

A quick and simple workaround is to create the temp table before the dynamic SQL and then just insert into it:

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TmpMemberTypeCount') is not null
    drop table #TmpMemberTypeCount

select *
into #TmpMemberTypeCount
from #TmpTbl
where 1 = 0

DECLARE @TmpMemberTypeCount NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @TmpMemberTypeCount =
    N'
INSERT INTO #TmpMemberTypeCount (cols....)
SELECT DISTINCT
        StoreID
        ,AgreedDate
        ,'+'''TotalCount'''+' as Type
        ,'+ @MemberTypeCols + '      
      FROM #TmpTbl as t

      PIVOT
      (
        SUM(CP_Count)
        FOR MemberShipType
        IN (' + @MemberTypePvt + ')
    ) as p
    GROUP BY StoreID
        ,AgreedDate'

EXEC (@TmpMemberTypeCount)
```

Comment: The #TmpMemberTypeCount table can be created with explicit create statement, in case fewer columns are needed (fewer than #TmpTbl has)

Comment: I don' think this will work because what is in `#TmpTbl` is not the format I need for the `#TmpMemberTypeCount`. #TmpTbl has a ROW for each MemberType whereas #TmpMemberTypeCount needs a COLUMN for each MemberType, And what complicates things is that the MemberTypes for each Store are different and never the same number.

Comment: Then you should create the #TmpMemberTypeCount with an explicit CREATE statement (with the appropriate columns and datatypes that are needed to store the values returned by the select statement in the dinamyc SQL).

Comment: Are you saying to CREATE the #TmpMemberTypeCount table in the dynamic query before the SELECT? If so, wouldn't that create the same issue where the #TmpMemberTypeCount table is only accessible within the EXEC?

Comment: no, create it with an explicit CREATE TABLE statement before the dynamic SQL (instead of select *
into #TmpMemberTypeCount
from #TmpTbl
where 1 = 0)

Comment: I would still need to use dynamic sql to get the column names. (see the update I made in my original post). the Variable @MemberTypeCols would be `User, Admin, Staff` So the CREATE TABLE would need to be `(CREATE TABLE...... (StoreID int, AgreedDate date, Type varchar(20), @MemberTypeCols)`

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Then it seems you should use a table variable. create a table variable (so not temp table) inside the dynamic SQL.